# What is optimal way to count number of actions per every day, hour and minute in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input is `time` which looks like this: (Its a huge dataset (in gb ) I am getting from another code) Each row is single value not two different columns.

```
2021-01-14 09:55:00
2021-01-14 09:56:54
2021-01-14 09:57:10
2021-01-14 07:51:13
2021-01-14 07:57:13
2021-01-14 08:49:41
2021-01-14 08:49:41
2021-01-08 08:53:34
2021-01-08 08:53:34
2021-01-08 08:53:34
2021-01-08 08:53:34
2021-01-08 08:53:34
2021-01-08 08:53:34
2021-01-08 07:52:18
2021-01-08 07:52:18
2021-01-08 07:52:18
2021-01-09 07:56:54
2021-01-09 07:56:54
2021-01-09 07:56:54
2021-01-09 09:52:17
2021-01-09 09:52:17
2021-01-09 09:52:17
2021-01-13 07:55:54
2021-01-13 07:49:12
2021-01-13 07:49:12
2021-01-10 07:55:00
2021-01-10 07:56:20
2021-01-10 07:53:22
```

Task is to count the number of actions **every day**,  **every hour** and **every minute** but only for top 2 days. (Already done)

```
    Date         Entries
    2021-01-14    7                            
    2021-01-08    9
```

Something like this, **This is day and hour.**

```
      Date   Hour    Entries
2021-01-14    7            2            
2021-01-14    8            2           
2021-01-14    9            3            
2021-01-08    7            3            
2021-01-08    10           2            
2021-01-08    11           4           
2021-01-08    18           5
```

Day, Hour, Minutes    Will look like this

```
      Date   Hour          Minutes  Entries
2021-01-14    5            1        10    
2021-01-14    5            50       5
2021-01-14    6            2        2   
2021-01-14    7            3        5    
2021-01-14    8           13        6   
2021-01-14    8           22        4   
2021-01-14    10           4        3  
2021-01-14    11           5        10
```

I am not sharing previous code here as I think irrelevant that how data is generated.

I am using Pandas dataframe for processing this.

Answer (score 1):

For compare I create helper column filled by dates by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), then for minimal and maximal datetimes is used [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) with filtering by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['date1'] = df['date'].dt.date
dates = df['date1'].agg(['min','max'])

df1 = df[df['date1'].isin(dates)]
print (df1)
                  date       date1
0  2021-01-14 09:55:00  2021-01-14
1  2021-01-14 09:56:54  2021-01-14
2  2021-01-14 09:57:10  2021-01-14
3  2021-01-14 07:51:13  2021-01-14
4  2021-01-14 07:57:13  2021-01-14
5  2021-01-14 08:49:41  2021-01-14
6  2021-01-14 08:49:41  2021-01-14
7  2021-01-08 08:53:34  2021-01-08
8  2021-01-08 08:53:34  2021-01-08
9  2021-01-08 08:53:34  2021-01-08
10 2021-01-08 08:53:34  2021-01-08
11 2021-01-08 08:53:34  2021-01-08
12 2021-01-08 08:53:34  2021-01-08
13 2021-01-08 07:52:18  2021-01-08
14 2021-01-08 07:52:18  2021-01-08
15 2021-01-08 07:52:18  2021-01-08
```

And for count is used [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df2 = df1.groupby('date1').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
        date1  count
0  2021-01-08      9
1  2021-01-14      7
```

With added [`Series.dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) and then
[`Series.dt.minute`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.minute.html):

```
df3 = df1.groupby(['date1',
                    df['date'].dt.hour.rename('Hour')]).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df3)
        date1  Hour  count
0  2021-01-08     7      3
1  2021-01-08     8      6
2  2021-01-14     7      2
3  2021-01-14     8      2
4  2021-01-14     9      3


df4 = df1.groupby(['date1', 
                   df['date'].dt.hour.rename('Hour'),
                   df['date'].dt.minute.rename('Minutes')]).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df4)
        date1  Hour  Minutes  count
0  2021-01-08     7       52      3
1  2021-01-08     8       53      6
2  2021-01-14     7       51      1
3  2021-01-14     7       57      1
4  2021-01-14     8       49      2
5  2021-01-14     9       55      1
6  2021-01-14     9       56      1
7  2021-01-14     9       57      1
```

Comment: @AdnanAli - I add for minutes and hours ouput, but it is different, there is something wrong?

Comment: I implement and test it on real dataset and then reply. it will take few time.